# JavaScript: Dragging Mouse on Links

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to make a calendar page where you can click and drag to select multiple calendar days at once.  Everything works fine in Google Chrome, but in Firefox, when I try to start dragging, it fails.  The reason for this is that each calendar day is contained in a link (`<a></a>`).  When you try to drag links in Firefox, it does its own action.  Is there any way I can prevent this or work around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this issue, saw your thread.  In my case, I handling the lower level mouse events, not click.  I found that on jQuery's mousedown (http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mousedown#fn) I could suppress Firefox's special behavior calling event.preventDefault (http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29) on the incoming mouse event.

I was calling it on other event handlers, but I suspect just mousedown() is sufficient to stop browsers from doing their custom drag behavior.

Comment: I thought I had tried that, but maybe I only tried event.preventDefault on click.  Either way, I just changed the links to divs, and that solved my problems.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm well maybe it's kinda late for this. But if you hadn't put this topic maybe I would have never resolved this. I had the same problem so I started to draw in my head how the events is working on.
The environment is this:

our draggable item:

```
<div id="sender"><a href="http://www.ourlinktodestination.com">my title</a></div>
```

our droppable item:

```
<table><tr><td class="celdarec">&nbsp;</td></tr><table>
```

So here is it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var globalEle, globalLink;

    $(".sender").draggable({
        revert:'invalid',
        start:function(event, ui){
            globalEle = $(this);
            globalLink = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        },
        stop:function(event, ui){
            globalEle = null;
        }
    });

    $("#tablareceptora .celdarec").droppable({
        accept: '.sender',
        hoverClass: 'drop_hover',
        drop: function(event, ui){
            $(this).html(globalEle.html());
            $(this).find("a").attr("href", globalLink);
            globalEle.remove();
        },
        tolerance: 'pointer'
    });

    $(".sender").delegate("a", "mouseup", function(e){
        e.target.href ="javascript:void(0)";
    });
});
```

(I'm using jQuery and jQuery ui from the wordpress folder so that's why the first line use "jQuery" statement instead of "$" and put this last on the handler as a parameter).

1. When you click to drag, the event.target.href is reached and filled with our link. For reasons that I can't explain (yet), even if you use preventDefault, on the mouseup event, using delegate statement, on the element passed to the droppable area, the link still redirects to it.
2. We are assuming the event is responding to the click action... "click" and that it means: Mouse down and Mouse up... but here is the thing: I used on the draggable "start" option this:

   ```
   globalLink = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
   ```

   globalLink is a declared variable externally (at the beginning of the script), so when you start to drag, the link is sent to this variable. Then, on the dragable element (in my case a class called sender) you must use the delegate statement, looking for an "a" marquee on the "mouseup" event and put "#" on the target.href setting of the event passed:

   ```
   $(".sender").delegate("a", "mouseup", function(e){
       e.target.href = "javascript:void(0)";
   });
   ```

   This will avoid any behavior that is working over the preventDefault statement (which I'm assuming is happening from the event who is evading this restriction).
3. Finally you drop your link on the "a" marquee. However if we just go and drop on the cell if you use firebug and check the code the href attribute has the "javascript:void(0)" that was passed on the mouseup event. This can answer many things, like how is the redirect behavior is fired in the drop action. Means jquery ui is working over the defaultPrevent because the redirect behavior on the droppable event, is a programmed behavior. So that's why I saved the link on the external variable, so I can reassign it on the drop event in the droppable setting:

   ```
   $(this).find("a").attr("href", globalLink);
   ```

Hope this can help any another guy or girl who is in the same situation

Good vibes for everyone!

Comment: Cool.  Instead of `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`, you can use: `jQuery(function($) {`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, do the following.
$( "a" ).click(function(){
return false;
});

return false prevents the browser's defaults.

Comment: I'm using jQuery, but that didn't work.  I tried Firefox's event.preventDefault(); as well.

Answer (score 0):

For IE you can also add:

```
    // prevent text selection in IE
    document.onselectstart = function () { return false; };
    // prevent IE from trying to drag an element
    target.ondragstart = function() { return false; };
```